# baguetteBox.js doesn't work and shows controls at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, baguettebox

I am using baguetteBox.js in a website in two different pages:

- homepage
- gallery

In the gallery it works well but in the homepage I can't find why the lightbox controls (i.e.:`id="baguetteBox-overlay"`) are appearing at the bottom of the webpage like this:

[image: screenshot]

In both webpages, I am loading the same assets, and console does not show any errors.

You can see it live at:

- homepage: http://keraban.marcanuy.com <- the one with the problem
- gallery: http://keraban.marcanuy.com/gallery/

Using _baguettebox.js/1.10.0 (with Bootstrap 4 too)

Any idea how to fix it?

## Relevant code:

In homepage,

```
<section class="gallery-block compact-gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">


            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item zoom-on-hover">
                <a class="lightbox" href="/media/images/image5.width-1400.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid image" src="/media/images/image5.width-1400.jpg">
                    <span class="description">
                        <span class="description-heading">Image 5</span>

                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item zoom-on-hover">
                <a class="lightbox" href="/media/images/image1.width-1400.jpg">
                    <img class="img-fluid image" src="/media/images/image1.width-1400.jpg">
                    <span class="description">
                        <span class="description-heading">Image 1</span>

                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            ....

    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Loading js at bottom:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
<script>
 baguetteBox.run('.compact-gallery', {
     animation: 'slideIn',
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base stylesheet was missing and caused the dialog to appear, adding the proper style sheet fixes it `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css" />`.